# WSL 2 GUI app windows dissapear sometimes

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wslg

does someone has an idea why a window of a GUI app running in WSL would dissapear from the task bar? The process is still running as seen with `ps all`, but the GUI cannot be accessed anymore.
This happens after standby and hybernat and I'm not sure, maybe also like this. In particular it's about pycharm (snap) and texstudio (apt).

This is very anoying since progress (in Python or LaTeX) for my studies can get lost this way...

```
~$ ps all
F   UID     PID    PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
4     0     258       1  20   0   3236    88 -      Ss+  hvc0       0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear --keep-baud console 115200,38400,9600 vt220
4     0     271       1  20   0   3192    80 -      Ss+  tty1       0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
4  1000     430     429  20   0 9545748 2145160 futex_ Ssl+ pts/0  87:49 /snap/pycharm-professional/336/jbr/bin/java -classpath [...]
4     0     431       2  20   0   7520   252 -      Ss   pts/1      0:00 /bin/login -f
4  1000     523     431  20   0   6120  1524 core_s S+   pts/1      0:00 -bash
0  1000     690     430  20   0   7452    88 -      S+   pts/0      0:03 /snap/pycharm-professional/336/bin/fsnotifier
0  1000    1290     430  20   0 1175836 18708 futex_ Sl+ pts/0      3:47 /home/xxxx/miniconda3/envs/gis/bin/python /snap/pycharm-professional/336/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=xxxxx
0  1000    3851     430  20   0 4310148 2501060 futex_ Sl+ pts/0    6:43 /home/xxxx/miniconda3/envs/gis/bin/python /snap/pycharm-professional/336/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=xxxxx
0  1000   12581     430  20   0 3146440 2388716 futex_ Sl+ pts/0    1:30 /home/xxxx/miniconda3/envs/gis/bin/python /snap/pycharm-professional/336/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=xxxxx
4  1000   14219   14217  20   0   6208  5036 do_wai Ss   pts/2      0:00 -bash
0  1000   14274   14219  20   0   7480  2968 -      R+   pts/2      0:00 ps all
```

Windows 11
10.0.22621.1848
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51

Ubuntu-22.04 LTS, windows store, WSL2: pycharm over snap
Debian 11, imported from tar ball, WSL2: texstudio over apt

The most recent Windows Event Log Message I could find (which was long before the incident) is in the Windows System log:
`Networking driver in xxxxxxxxxx is loaded and the protocol version is negotiated to the most recent version (Virtual machine ID xxxxxxxxxx).`

I don't know, what to search for or which other information to provide since there is no error message anywhere.

Thanks a lot in advance already for any hint and best regards